# What's the difference between these two enum definitions?

Tags: objective-c, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [enum values: NSInteger or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496903/enum-values-nsinteger-or-int)

What's the difference between these two enum definitions?

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    Honda = 1,
    Chevrolet = 2,
    Mercedes = 3,
    Volvo = 4
} CarManufacturer;
```

and

```
enum {
    HarleyDavidson = 1,
    BMW = 2,
    Yamaha = 3,
    Kawasaki = 4,
};
typedef NSUInteger MotorcycleManufacturer;
```

Comment: About 600 horsepower, I would guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are essentially the same thing. The difference is that the first one is more "C++-styled" and the second one is more "C-Styled".

C++ makes some semantic differences, but you can write C-Style enums (that are present throughout the Cocoa frameworks) for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I would say the main difference is that one is an anonymous enum while the other is not...